# Get a thread to run a function multiple times in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have this school assignment asking us to perform Gaussian Elimination with partial pivoting in an NxN matrix with any given number of threads where number of threads <= N. I got it up till the point where I can do it with N threads. Can someone explain how I could have 2 threads, for example, perform Gaussian elimination on a matrix 8x8. I'd love an explanation instead of a solution since this is a school project.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 8
double A[N][N+1];
pthread_barrier_t barrier;

int print_matrix()
{
   int i, j;
   printf("------------------------------------\n");
   for(i=0; i<N; i++){
       for(j=0;j<N+1;j++)
          printf("%6.2f  ",  A[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
   }
}

void *ge(void *arg) // threads function: Gauss elimination
{
  int i, j, k, prow;
  int myid = (int)arg;
  double temp, factor;
  for(i=0; i<N-1; i++){
     if (i == myid){
        printf("partial pivoting by thread %d on row %d: ", myid, i);
        temp = 0.0; prow = i;
        for (j=i; j<=N; j++){
            if (fabs(A[j][i]) > temp){
               temp = fabs(A[j][i]);
           prow = j;
        }
        }
        printf("pivot_row=%d  pivot=%6.2f\n", prow, A[prow][i]);
        if (prow != i){  // swap rows
        for (j=i; j<N+1; j++){
          temp = A[i][j];
              A[i][j] = A[prow][j];
              A[prow][j] = temp;
            }
    } 
     }
     // wait for partial pivoting done
     pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier); 
     for(j=i+1; j<N; j++){
        if (j == myid){ 
           printf("thread %d do row %d\n", myid, j);
       factor = A[j][i]/A[i][i];
           for (k=i+1; k<=N; k++)
               A[j][k] -= A[i][k]*factor;
       A[j][i] = 0.0;
        }
     }
     // wait for current row reductions to finish 
     pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
     if (i == myid)
        print_matrix();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, j;
  double sum;
  pthread_t threads[N];
 
  printf("main: initialize matrix A[N][N+1] as [A|B]\n"); 
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        A[i][j] = 1.0;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
      A[i][N-i-1] = 1.0*N;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
      A[i][N] = (N*(N+1))/2 + (N-i)*(N - 1);
  }
  print_matrix();  // show initial matrix [A|B]

  pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, N); // set up barrier

  printf("main: create N=%d working threads\n", N);
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ge, (void *)i);
  }
  printf("main: wait for all %d working threads to join\n", N);
  for (i=0; i<N; i++){
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  printf("main: back substitution : ");
  for (i=N-1; i>=0; i--){
      sum = 0.0;
      for (j=i+1; j<N; j++)
          sum += A[i][j]*A[j][N];
      A[i][N] = (A[i][N]- sum)/A[i][i];
  }
  // print solution
  printf("The solution is :\n");
  for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    printf("%6.2f  ", A[i][N]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Pick **a** language, because modern c++ would make this one helluvalot less cumbersome than you're showing here.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you declare a function to return a value, you must really return something, even if it's never used. Also `(void *)i` is a bad cast, you really need to cast in two steps here: `(void *) (intptr_t) i`. Then do the opposite cast in the thread function: `int myid = (int) (intptr_t) arg;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my professor told me to do that. He seems to want it a specific way and it just makes this way harder.

Comment: @WhozCraig sadly, it has to be in C and this is how my professor wants it :(

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch alright, will mention it to him :)

Comment: @DayemSaeed *" my professor told me to do that."* - does your professor architect/engineer code for a living? No? Like the rest of academia, take what the profs say as *guidance*, but do your own homework and determine what is fact vs. fiction. Basile has some solid links, and I *strongly* advise you do a little drilling.

Comment: @WhozCraig honestly, I do avoid stuff like that but idk. This professor just grades real harshly, taking off points if you didn't do something a certain way even if it works. But I will take your advice and do more homework instead of _ just_ relying on the professor